# What is the maximum number of 2560x1600 monitor a single graphics card can support?

Tags: gpu

What is the maximum number of 2560x1600 monitors a single **< 1000 $** graphics card can support? Please name this card.

Comment: Not only is this a shopping recommendation question (which is not allowed here, read the FAQ), it is also too localized since what's possible at a specific price point will never remain static, especially considering rapid technology advances.

Comment: I didn't ask to buy the card. Just serious what is the maximum number of 2560x1600 monitors a single PC can support. I am sorry for the price part it was latter added to avoid 5K GPUs.

Comment: Well, the price part clearly makes it seem like a shopping recommendation.

Comment: I am new here so... Can I something to fix this? Also, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Actually, even your question [as originally stated](http://superuser.com/revisions/545195/1) was about the max. no. of monitors of XxY resolution a single graphics card can support, and then you wanted the name of the card that would satisfy this requirement (again a shopping recommendation, plus too localized since some other card will probably come along that supports more such monitors). As for fixing it, irrespective of whether this is closed I guess you already got an answer as to the best card *right now* that satisfies your requirements.

Comment: OK, I see your point...

Comment: Like Karan said. If you *know* your question—rather, it's answers—won't be useful to anyone in, say 6 months, then it's probably too localized. Sorry about that, but consider coming to [chat] for requests like this!

Comment: OK, please don't downvote anymore... :(

Comment: A down vote is automatically cast by the system when questions are closed as "off topic" or "not a real question", don't worry all too much about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Four, Quadro NVS 420 http://www.nvidia.com/object/product_quadro_nvs_420_us.html. I've used this in the past, works great.

Comment: Thanks! What is the speed of the 4 Monitors? I mean, can I play a video across all monitors without lag etc? Of cource no question about gaming. Also, seems dated (2010) is there something more recent?

Comment: Found it, NVS 450 and 510. Thanks for your help!